How to avoid the pre_shared_key extension in the server hello which is generated by a reused SSL * structure
I am using openssl 1.1.1w lib.
I calls SSL_clear after a https connection is closed, and reuse the SSL * structure for a new connection.
But for the new connection, openssl generated a pre_shared_key extension in the server hello.
Because the new client hello does not contains any pre_shared_key extensions, the client send an fatal alert.
In the source code, tls_construct_stoc_psk function constructs psk extension if s->hit is true. And s->hit means that the session is a reused one.
Calling SSL_set_session(s, NULL) after SSL_clear can avoid the pre_shared_key extensions, but SSL_SESSION_free in SSL_set_session may affect the performance.
Are there any other ways to avoid the pre_shared_key extension except calling SSL_set_session(s, NULL)?
SSL_set_session(s, NULL) works, but increases many memory alloc and free.

According to the document https://docs.openssl.org/1.1.1/man3/SSL_clear/#synopsis ,  the session object will be kept and all settings corresponding , SSL_set_session(s, NULL) seems to be the only way to solve the problem.
